# For some reason data is not sent from 3rd Activity to main Activity and the app crashes while the 2nd Activity works perfectly fine

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
package com.example.intent;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etEnterName;
    Button btnActivity2;
    Button btnActivity3;
    TextView tvMessage;
    final int ACTIVITY3=3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etEnterName=findViewById(R.id.etEnterName);
        btnActivity2=findViewById(R.id.btnActivity2);
        btnActivity3=findViewById(R.id.btnActivity3);

        btnActivity2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (etEnterName.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                else {
                    String name = etEnterName.getText().toString().trim();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            com.example.intent.Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

        btnActivity3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        com.example.intent.Activity3.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,ACTIVITY3);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==ACTIVITY3)
        {
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                tvMessage.setText(data.getStringExtra("surname"));
            }
            if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
                tvMessage.setText("no data received");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**3rd Activity**

```
package com.example.intent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnSubmit;
    EditText etSurname;
    Button btnCancel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

        btnSubmit=findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        etSurname=findViewById(R.id.etSurname);
        btnCancel=findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(etSurname.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Activity3.this,"please enter your surname" Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    String surname = etSurname.getText().toString().trim();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("surname",surname);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    Activity3.this.finish();

                }
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                Activity3.this.finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**This is the manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intent">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activity3"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Explanation**

> Blockquote

*I following a youtube video and i cant find where i am getting the whole thing wrong. The button main activity works perfectly fine and take me to the third intent but when i enter data in edit text box and click the submit button the app crashes.*

Comment: i had not added this line of code. tvMessage = findviewbyid (R.id.tvMessage);            My bad

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your answer. This will help others who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not added this line of code.
tvMessage = findviewbyid (R.id.tvMessage);
My bad –